# PowerShell Data Types and Hashtable MCA_Decode

Tags: .net, powershell, hashtable

This is my first attempt at scripting in any language. I know what I would like to do, but could use some help finding what I'm looking for. This is a side project for my own learning and fun :)

1. Takes 1 argument (two byte hex, or binary)
2. Compares against error mask
3. Write-Host with explanation

Currently data types for are all probably string. Do I need these to be `int`? `int32`? `int64`?

The error masks are simple assigned to variables

```
$IO_Error = 0000111000001011
```

Would it be more efficient to store these as a "Hashtable"

```
$ErrorList = @{IO_Error, 0000111000001011; so, on; so, on;}
```

Then be able to foreach check if match?

This works well for simple errors however getting into the compound error codes and masks I need to be able to refer to and check certain offsets to see what bits are set to ensure an accurate decode.

```
<#
# =====================
#  Simple Error Codes                        # Table 15-8. IA32_MCi_Status [15:0] Simple Error Code Encoding
# =====================                      # 64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462. Volume 3B 
#  
#
#          Error Desc                  Error Mask          Error Code Binary Encoding Meaning
# No Error                          0000 0000 0000 0000 No error has been reported to this bank of error-reporting registers.
# Unclassified                      0000 0000 0000 0001 This error has not been classified into the MCA error classes.
# Microcode ROM Parity Error        0000 0000 0000 0010 Parity error in internal microcode ROM
# External Error                    0000 0000 0000 0011 The BINIT# from another processor caused this processor to enter machine check.*1
# FRC Error                         0000 0000 0000 0100 FRC (functional redundancy check) master/slave error
# Internal Parity Error             0000 0000 0000 0101 Internal parity error.
# SMM Handler Code Access Violation 0000 0000 0000 0110 An attempt was made by the SMM Handler to execute outside the ranges specified by SMRR.
# Internal Timer Error              0000 0100 0000 0000 Internal timer error.
# I/O Error                         0000 1110 0000 1011 generic I/O error.
# Internal Unclassified             0000 01xx xxxx xxxx Internal unclassified errors. *2
#
#
# =====================
# Compound Error Codes                       # Table 15-9 IA32_MCi_Status [15:0] Compound Error Code Encounding
# =====================                      # 64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462. Volume 3B 
#
#
#         Error Desc                  Error Mask          Error Code Binary Encoding Meaning
# Generic Cache Hierarchy          000F 0000 0000 11LL Generic cache hierarchy error
# TLB Errors                       000F 0000 0001 TTLL {TT}TLB{LL}_ERR
# Memory Controller Errors         000F 0000 1MMM CCCC {MMM}_CHANNEL{CCCC}_ERR
# Cache Hierarchy Errors           000F 0001 RRRR TTLL {TT}CACHE{LL}_{RRRR}_ERR
# Bus and Interconnect Errors      000F 1PPT RRRR IILL BUS{LL}_{PP}_{RRRR}_{II}_{T}_ERR
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#>
Function MCA_Decode
{
$No_Error = 0000000000000000
$Unclassified = 0000000000000001
$Microcode_ROM_Parity_Error = 0000000000000010
$External_Error = 0000000000000011
$FRC_Error = 0000000000000100
$Internal_Parity_Error = 0000000000000101
$SMM_Handler_Code_Access_Violation = 0000000000000110
$Internal_Timer_Error = 0000010000000000
$IO_Error = 0000111000001011
#$Internal_Unclassified = 000001xx xxxx xxxx
#
#
$input = $args[0]
if($input -eq $No_Error){
Write-Host "Error Type: No Error`nError Desc: No error has been reported to this bank of error-reporting registers." -ForegroundColor Green
}
if($input -eq $Unclassified){
Write-Host "Error Type: Unclassified`nError Desc: This error has not been classified into the MCA error classes." -ForegroundColor Green
}
if($input -eq $Microcode_ROM_Parity_Error){
Write-Host "Error Type: Microcode ROM Parity Error`nError Desc: Parity error in internal microcode ROM" -ForegroundColor Green
}
if($input -eq $External_Error){
Write-Host "Error Type: External Error`nError Desc: The BINIT# from another processor caused this processor to enter machine check." -ForegroundColor Green
}
if($input -eq $FRC_Error){
Write-Host "Error Type: FRC Error`nError Desc: FRC (functional redundancy check) master/slave error" -ForegroundColor Green
}
if($input -eq $Internal_Parity_Error){
Write-Host "Error Type: Internal Parity Error`nError Desc: Internal parity error." -ForegroundColor Green
}
if($input -eq $SMM_Handler_Code_Access_Violation){
Write-Host "Error Type: SMM Handler Code Access Violation`nError Desc: An attempt was made by the SMM Handler to execute outside the ranges specified by SMRR." -ForegroundColor Green
}
if($input -eq $Internal_Timer_Error){
Write-Host "Error Type: Internal Timer Error`Error Desc: Internal timer error." -ForegroundColor Green
}
if($input -eq $IO_Error){
Write-Host "Error Type: I/O Error`Error Desc: generic I/O error." -ForegroundColor Green
}
}
MCA_Decode $args[0]
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the variables are in fact all "string" 
$IO_Error.GetTypeCode()
String

Comment: Just to clarify, the variables are in fact all "string" 
$IO_Error.GetTypeCode()
String 

So I can easy send my variable to | gm however for someone who's never played with this before the definition is not something that is easily interpreted for example this one is easy enough 
Length           Property              int Length {get;} 

if ($input.Length -le 4) {[convert]::ToString("$input", 2)}..... 
I know two byte hex input would be 4 chars long so this could test and if hex I can convert to the binary. 

What is not clear is do I need these values to be Ints and what kind

Answer (score 0):

A hashtable could certainly help you resolve individual errors.

May I suggest defining your error code values in hex, PowerShell parses it natively and it's way easier to read IMO.

Also, if you plan to introduce compound errors, make sure each bit represents a distinct primitive error.

You could do something like:

```
function Get-ErrorDescription {
    param(
        [int]$ErrorCode,
        [switch]$All
    )

    $ErrorCodes = @{
        0x0000 = 'No_Error'
        0x0001 = 'Unclassified'
        0x0002 = 'Microcode_ROM_Parity_Error'
        0x0004 = 'External_Error'
        0x0008 = 'FRC_Error'
        0x0010 = 'Internal_Parity_Error'
        0x0020 = 'SMM_Handler_Code_Access_Violation'
        0x0040 = 'Internal_Timer_Error'
        0x0080 = 'IO_Error'
        0x0100 = 'IRQ_Error'
        0x0062 = 'Compound_Error'
    }

    if(-not $All -or $ErrorCode -eq 0){
        # default, return just the exact error
        return $ErrorCodes[$ErrorCode]
    }

    # Sort keys, filter out No_Error and test the $ErrorCode against each errorcode value with binary AND, output the error description
    return $ErrorCodes.Keys |Sort-Object |Where-Object {$_ -ne 0 -and (($ErrorCode -band $_) -eq $_)}|ForEach-Object { $ErrorCodes[$_] }
}
```

Now you can resolve errors by value:

```
PS C:\> Get-ErrorDescription 0x0000
No_Error
PS C:\> Get-ErrorDescription 0x0001
Unclassified
PS C:\> Get-ErrorDescription 0x0062
Compound_Error
PS C:\> Get-ErrorDescription 0x0062
Microcode_ROM_Parity_Error
SMM_Handler_Code_Access_Violation
Internal_Timer_Error
Compound_Error
PS C:\> Get-ErrorDescription 0x0013
Unclassified
Microcode_ROM_Parity_Error
Internal_Parity_Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assistance. 
I was able to get everything working using help from this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx

```
function Get-MCAError{
[CmdletBinding()]
[string]$Errorcode = $args[0]
$ErrorCodes = @{
    '0x0000'    =    'Verbose message here';
...5000+ lines
}#end of hash table
if ($ErrorCodes.ContainsKey($Errorcode) -eq $True){
$Decode_Message = $ErrorCodes.get_item($Errorcode)
Write-Host $Decode_Message -ForegroundColor Green
} #End of hash lookup 
else {
Write-Host "Error Not Found, or Internal Unclassified" -ForegroundColor Red
} #End of Else 
} #End of Get-MCAError Function 
Get-MCAError $args[0]
```